# How to check strtotime value and database value in laravel

Tags: sql-server, date, laravel-4

I have table `wys_attendances(id,t_id, t_date,t_month_t_year,t_attend)`

I am trying to fetch one full month attendances from `wys_attendance` table like pivot table format.
rows base teacher name and column base full month day `(1/2/2015,2/2/2015....28/2/2015)`
I got this format output  by using this code
 my controller

```
 $teacher = WysTeacher::all();
 $dayCount = date('t', strtotime('01-'. $amonth . '-' . $ayear));
 for($i = 1; $i <= $dayCount; $i++)
```

my view blade.php

```
 <tr class="tbl-head">
 <td>Teacher Name</td>
 @for($i = 1; $i <= $dayCount; $i++)
 <td>{{$i}}</td>
 @endfor
 </tr>
 @foreach($teacher as $teachers)
 <tr>   
 <td>{{$teachers->tname}}</td>
 @endforeach
 </tr>
```

Then I am trying to display `attendance(present() p/absend(a))` below in column date and also corrseponding teachername by usinf this code

```
@foreach($attendance as $attendances)
                  @if($teachers->id == $attendances->t_auserid)  
                  @if($attendances->t_attendance == 1)
                  <td><font color="green">p</font></td>
                  @elseif($attendances->t_attendance == 0)
                  <td><font color="red">a</font></td>    
                  @endif
                  @endif
 @endforeach
```

It's work fine, but the problem is attendance marked at not corresponding date.

if `1/2/2015` date not in database and `2.2/2015` is in database all present(p).
but display in view page column `1/2/2015`  below marked p value and `2/2/2015` below marked next day attendance .

How to check month date and database value is correct? And display attendance at correcponding date below.